# Laravel REST API

Tags: laravel, rest

I use Laravel as framework and generate API by JSON and the I use PHP to get JSON data and delete data by route API in laravel but it's seem to be not working.
My API Route in laravel:

```
Route::delete('/subject/{id}', [SubjectController::class, 'deleteSubject']);
```

My controller

```
public function deleteSubject($id)
{
        $subject = Subject::find($id);

        if (!$subject) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Subject not found'], 404);
    }

        $subject->delete();

            return response()->json(['message' => 'Subject deleted successfully'], 200);
}
```

localhost

http://localhost:8000/api/subject/13

I've tried everything and nothing happens. There's no error in the code upon running.

Comment: Have you tried to write anything to the logs? Is the controller method ran?

Comment: `Route::delete...` Are you sending a `DELETE` verb/method? Simply calling http://localhost:8000/api/subject/13 in your browser will send a `GET` request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the route is defined in routes/api.php rather than in the web.php
That might be the cause because your code is correct and calling the endpoint is okay

Comment: That route already seems to be taken from `api.php`